# passing ‘function as ‘this’ argument of ’function' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, linked-list, stack

one of my copy constructors for my stack ADT using a linked list seems to work mostly except for one error that it is causing. It obviously has something to do with the "other" StackLinked being a const type and the pop() function is altering it, but could explain to me how I can do this by keeping "other" to still be const if possible. If not, is how else could I go about doing this.

Here is the copy constructor:

```
template <typename DataType>
StackLinked<DataType>::StackLinked(const StackLinked<DataType> & other)
{   
    int tempSize = other.getSize();
    StackLinked<DataType> temp = StackLinked<DataType>();
    for(int i = 0; i < tempSize; i++)
    {
        temp.push(other.pop()); //error is on this line on the pop function
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < tempSize; i++)
    {
        push(temp.pop());
    }
}
```

Here is the pop() and push() functions:

```
template <typename DataType>
DataType StackLinked<DataType>::pop()
{  
        StackNode * temp = top->next;
        delete top;
        top = temp;
        size--;  
}
template <typename DataType>
    void StackLinked<DataType>::push(const DataType & newDataItem) 
    {
        StackNode * temp = top;
        top = new StackNode(newDataItem, temp);
        size++;
    }
```

And the main function just simply creates a new StackLinked object:

```
#include "StackLinked.h"
#include "StackLinked.cpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    StackLinked<int> test = StackLinked<int>();
}
```

Finally, the error:

```
StackLinked.cpp:21:9: error: passing ‘const StackLinked<int>’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘DataType StackLinked<DataType>::pop() [with DataType = int]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
         temp.push(other.pop());
```

Comment: Look at the type of `other`.  Does anything about it tell you that it can't be modified?

Comment: so should I just remove const?

Comment: @BenjaminNordin No, then copying a stack would empty it. You'll have to rely on implementation details, probably iterator over `top->next`.

Comment: @BenjaminNordin No, you need to build a new list that is a copy of the one in other.

Answer (score 0):

> , but could explain to me how I can do this by keeping "other" to still be const if possible.

Instead of using `other.pop()`, you can simply use the member variables of `other` directly.

```
template <typename DataType>
StackLinked<DataType>::StackLinked(const StackLinked<DataType> & other)
{   
    StackLinked<DataType> temp = StackLinked<DataType>();
    StackNode<DataType>* node = other.top;
    while ( node != nullptr )
    {
        temp.push(node->data); // I am guessing data is a member variable of StackNode.
                               // If not, use the right member variable.
        node = node->next;
    }

    node = temp.top;
    while ( node != nullptr )
    {
        push(node->data);
        node = node->next;
    }
}
```